# Is dakhsa daughter lakshmi mata the same mata lakshmi who is lord vishnu wife

Tags: puranas, lakshmi, daksha, genealogy

The daughter of dakhsha lakshmi maa who is married to dharma.Is she the same lakshmi maa who is Lord vishnu wife?

Comment: Where is Lakshmi? —-> Śraddhā, Maitrī, Dayā, Śānti, Tuṣṭi, Puṣṭi, Kriyā, Unnati, Buddhi, Medhā, Titikṣā, Hrī and Mūrti

Comment: never heard this.. do you mean Daksha's granddaughter Laxmi (Daksha -> Khyati -> Laxmi)?? If so she was an incarnation of Goddess Laxmi and was married to Lord Vishnu...